# Setting up Phonegap for iOS - Command /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, cordova

I just installed the iPhone SDK 3.1.3. (Latest version that runs on Mac OSX 10.5.8)
After that I installed the latest phonegap-version and followed the getting started guide to build a test-app:

http://www.phonegap.com/start/

But when I try to compile the project, the Compiler throws 2 errors:

- **Building target "PhoneGapLib" of project "PhoneGapLib" with
  configuration "Release" - (1 error)**    Precompiling

  - PhoneGapLib_Prefix.pc (1 error)

    - llvm-gcc-4.2: Invalid arch name : armv6

      - *Command /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit
        code 1*

-

- **Building target "testapp" of project "testapp" with
  configuration "Release" - (1 error)**    Precompiling

  - Checking Dependencies

    - *Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate /private key pair in the default keychain*

It strictly followed the guide and googled the errors, but I couldn't find any good information about this problem or figure it out, as I don't know the SDK, Phonegap or Xcode in special. To me it looks like some basic filelink would be missing or something, but I couldn't find any information on this error in particular too, so I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: It looks like the used compiler is not supported by the sdk. But how do I change the compiler? In the project setting I can only select "com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42" as Compiler.

Comment: This keeps confusing me. Everywhere I look, I get the infos that xcode offers more than one compiler per default, but I can't find any other than gcc4.2. And the information how to install gcc on mac was: "Install xcode". I already did that.